# getting back original project

Tags: git, github

I had some python code save on github site here...

https://github.com/shantanuo/syllabalize_unicode

```
I made some mistake and it was overwritten.
```

How do I get back the original script written by me?

These are the commands I used so far:

```
  git add README
  git commit -m 'first commit'
  git remote add origin git@github.com:shantanuo/syllabalize_unicode.git
  git push -u origin master
```

Comment: That can't possibly overwrite anything. The push is not forced, so it can't destroy history.

Comment: There is nothing in that repository except a `README` file. What is the "original script" you are referring to?

Comment: You can see a list of all commits [here](https://github.com/shantanuo/syllabalize_unicode/commits/master), though there doesn't seem to be anything substantial in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can revert that unwanted commit using **git revert**
To get manual page of revert run **git revert --help**